# How to apply Grammatical Evolution string to a solution

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am learning Grammatical Evolution, but one thing that I can't seem to grasp is how to use the strings that are evolved from grammar into solving an actual problem. Is it converted into a neural network or converted into an equation, or something else? How does it receive inputs and print out outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Grammatical Evolution (GE) makes distinction between genotype and phenotype ([genotype–phenotype distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genotype%E2%80%93phenotype_distinction)), which means an evolved genotype is not a solution by itself, but it *maps* to a solution.

Mutations and crossover are performed over genotypes, but to evaluate the fitness a genotype should be first transformed into a phenotype. In Grammatical Evolution this means generation of a string conforming to the chosen grammar. This solution string then should be *executed*, and the result of the execution evaluated to estimate the fitness of the solution.

#### How to actually execute the generated solution?

It highly depends on the implementation of a GE system.

If it generates solutions in some real programming language, they should be compiled and/or executed with the corresponding toolchain, ran with some test input, and  the output evaluated to estimate the fitness.

If a GE system is able to execute a solution internally, no external toolchain is involved. It might be convenient to **generate a syntax tree**-like structure according to the grammar (instead of unstructured text), because it's quite easy to execute such a structure.

#### How to execute a syntax tree?

There exist an entire class of so called tree walk interpreters — not super performant, but reasonably simple in implementation. Usually such an interpreter first parses a source text and builds a syntax tree, then executes it; but in a GE system it is possible to directly generate a syntax tree, so no parsing is involved.

I can suggest ["A tree-walk interpreter"](http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/a-tree-walk-interpreter.html) chapter of a freely available book ["Crafting interpreters"](http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/) as a good example of constructing such an interpreter.